# Does Irukandji only have one level?

Tags: irukandji

After ship selection, Irukandji opens saying:

[image]

This suggests there's more than one level, but after I defeat the crab boss fight at the end, the game simply ends and a new ship is unlocked.

Is that it?

Comment: From promotional descriptions there appears to only be one level

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is only one level.  I think the game was never fully completed, so while it still says 'level 1' at the beginning, it is in fact, the only level.

Comment: I mean, it *is* level 1...

Comment: History of the World, Part 1